# How to check if an email is already registered using fetchSignInMethodsForEmail in JS?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I would like to know how to use the use fetchSignInMethodsForEmail to see if an email address is already in use. I tried to make a solution but it only works if the password is the same.

So if you registered
email:test@gmail
Password: 123test

and tried to signup again with
email:test@gmail
password:321test

it does not alert the user that the email is already in use.

Thanks for your time

Here is my current code

```
function signUp(email,password){
  //Check if email adress registerd then password security
  firebase.auth().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email)
    .then((signInMethods) => {
      if (signInMethods.length) {
        alert("Aldready signed up with this email")
      } else {
        // User does not exist. Ask user to sign up.
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Some error occurred.
    });
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify I want it to alert the user that the email is in use even if the password is different

Comment: How did you register the user with that given email address (the password is irrelevant here)?

Comment: I used createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Comment: Can you confirm if you have enabled the the setting to allow/disallow multiple accounts per email? Firebase allows you to have multiple accounts per email if the sign-in methods you use is different, I don't think it looks for email/password combination to distinguish.  [Documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9134820?hl=en&ref_topic=6386702)

Comment: It is set to enabled

Comment: The only reason why I want to do this is to inform the user that the email address is already registered

Comment: You can leave the box unchecked for that, if you use this method. But I'm not sure why `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` doesn't return the `password` provider in your case.

Comment: It is still not working. Can you please give me a basic code that detects if an email was registered? I would greatly appreciate that.